# php null replacement function

Tags: php, string, null, replace

there is this function called Nz() in visual basic for application. the function checks variable nullity and returns a provided value if it finds the variable is null.

i try to write the same function in php, which looks like below:

```
function replace_null($value, $replace) {
    if (!isset($value)) {
        return $replace;
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}

$address = replace_null($data['address'], 'Address is not available.');
```

of course, if `$data['address']` is found null, php will stop executing the code and `replace_null` won't be called.

i'm currently using ternary

```
(isset(data['address']) ? data['address'] : 'Address is not available.');
```

but i think `replace_null`, if it works, will offer a more convenient way.

is there a function in php that provide the same functionality as vba's Nz()? 
any suggestion will be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that a variable with the value `null` and a variable that doesn't exist are two different things. Try this: `$foo = null; echo $foo; echo $bar;`

Comment: it really surprises me that all this time i thought they were the same. and in my case, null variable isn't the only i want to check, but also the non-existent. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit roundabout: If you only use this to check for array members, you could pass the key separately:

```
function get_with_default($arr, $key, $defval)
{
  return isset($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : $defval;
}
```

If the variable could be set but null (*Edit:* which it cannot, thanks @deceze), add another check:

```
function get_and_coalesce_with_default($arr, $key, $defval)
{
  return (isset($arr[$key]) && !is_null($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : $defval;
}
```

As pointed out, `isset()` only succeeds on non-null values, so the above doesn't add anything. We can write a non-trivial check with `array_key_exists`, though:

```
function get_with_default_v2($arr, $key, $defval)
{
  return (array_key_exists($key, $arr) && !is_null($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : $defval;
}
```

Comment: If the variable `isset`, then it's also not `null`. `isset` returns `false` for `null` values.

Comment: @deceze: Oh OK. In that case, you don't need the second version. So are variables that are set to `null` entirely indistinguishable from non-existing variables within the language (i.e. testing by causing an error is not allowed)?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Variables with the value `null` and non existing *variables* cannot be distinguished without causing a warning. For arrays you can use `array_key_exists`, with returns `true` even for `null` values.

Comment: @deceze: Oh, that array lookup maybe even nicer for the present workaround - let me edit that in! Hm, maybe exception handling could be used to track an illegal access, i.e. call a dummy function and see if the call fails because the argument isn't a variable...

Comment: Warnings are not exceptions. And really, don't overcomplicate this basic thing. If you're accessing non-existing variables, you *should* get a warning because something's wrong in your logic.

Comment: @kerrek thanks for the solution. yes, at this time i only want to check for array members. i have ideas to expand its functionality, but for now i'm just happy my code looks simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the array and the key separately like this:

```
function valueOrDefault($array, $key, $default) {
    return isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}

$address = valueOrDefault($data, 'address', 'Address is not available.');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass by reference, PHP won't error out:

```
function Nz(&$var, $def='') {
    return isset($var) ? $var : $def;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is declared you do something like $value?:$replace

Answer (score 1):

```
function replace_null($value='', $replace='') {
    if (!isset($value)) {
        return $replace;
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Try this. It will allow you to call the function with or without passing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
function replace_null($value, $replace) {
    if(empty($value) && $value !== '0') {
        return $replace;
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}

$address = replace_null("0", "replacing null");
echo $address;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using the [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function would be much more useful:

```
$address = $data['address'];
if ( is_null($address) ) $address = 'Address is not available.';
```

If you really want this as a function:

```
function replace_null($value, $replace) {
    if (is_null($value)) return $replace;
    return $value;
}
$address = replace_null($data['address'], 'Address is not available.');
```