# remove null when the value is empty in an array replace it by quotes in json in php

Tags: php, json

How can i remove the value "**null**", when the array value is empty?

I just added the following to convert the json format:

```
for( $cnt=0; $cnt<$iNumberOfPics; $cnt++ )
    {
  $output[]=array('video_img_url'=>$img[$cnt],'video_url'=>$vid[$cnt],'views'=>$view[$cnt],'video_title'=>$title[$cnt]);
   }
  $json_result=json_encode($output);
  echo $json_result;
```

So i'm getting the result as follows:

```
{"video_img_url":"http:\/\/ffff.com\/fff-ffff\/fff\/ffff\/05\/fff-ff-ff-AX-fff.jpg","video_url":"http:\/\/ffff.com\/ff-fff\/fff\/fff\/11\/ffBIKE-ffAX 050814.mov","views":null,"video_title":null}
```

I want to get the result as:

```
{"video_img_url":"http:\/\/ffff.com\/fff-ffff\/fff\/ffff\/05\/fff-ff-ff-AX-fff.jpg","video_url":"http:\/\/ffff.com\/ff-fff\/fff\/fff\/11\/ffBIKE-ffAX 050814.mov","views":"","video_title":""}
```

Can anyone help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101820/php-null-replacement-function...check this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this before the encoding:

```
foreach ($output as $var=>$val) { if ($val==null) {$output[$var]='';}}
```

Comment: what should be come in the place of $var? @Gipsz Jakab

Comment: '' is a string which is empty, while null is a null value ...
I've checked the solution before i've posted it ...

Comment: i have tried it but i did not get the answer @ Gipsz Jakab...Sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array('abc' =>'test', 'test'=> 'adsf');
foreach ($arr as $var => $val) {
    if ($val === null) {
        $arr[$var] = '';
    }
}
$json_result = json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i add the following code to get my result.

```
 for( $cnt=0; $cnt<$iNumberOfPics; $cnt++ )
    {

         if ($view[$cnt]) $viewcount=$view[$cnt]; else $viewcount="";
         if ($title[$cnt]) $titles=$title[$cnt]; else $titles="";

      $output[]=array('video_img_url'=>$img[$cnt],'video_url'=>$vid[$cnt],'views'=>$viewcount,'video_title'=>$titles);

    } 

echo json_encode($output);
```

Thanks all!!

Comment: basically you did the same thing like we've suggested you.
But you did not accapted any of our solutions ... 
I suggest next time you solve your own problems ...

Comment: sorry i tried it,but i have not get my result,thats why i did not accept your answer.This is not a good way to say like this.If i got my answer then i will surely accept this.Now you want to accept your answer know.ok i will do it. @Gipsz Jakab

Comment: I've just told you the solution: add the line before the json_encode ...
for( $cnt=0; $cnt<$iNumberOfPics; $cnt++ )
    {
  $output[]=array('video_img_url'=>$img[$cnt],'video_url'=>$vid[$cnt],'views'=>$view[$cnt],'video_title'=>$title[$cnt]);
   }
foreach ($output as $var=>$val) { if ($val==null) {$output[$var]='';}}  
$json_result=json_encode($output);
  echo $json_result;

it's so simple ... the line i created for you checks if any variable is null, and replaces it with "" which is a string (which is empty, but already a string!)

Comment: Where you have mentioned this solution before this @Gipsz Jakab?just review your answer post.

Comment: "

Run this before the encoding:

foreach ($output as $var=>$val) { if ($val==null) {$output[$var]='';}}

"

This was my FIRST answer ...
run the line BEFORE the encoding ...
endocing =json_encode ...